# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

In my Lightning component I can see error in this line can anyone help me to resolve.

var recordsList = component.get("v.caseRecord.Primary_Consumable__r.Chemistries__c").split(';');

Thanks
Biswa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `undefined.split(';')` in browser console you get the same error that means the component does not have a value set before the split is called. I would first check for null then call split method